# PHPExcel: Repeated process increases peak memory usage

Tags: php, memory-management, phpunit, phpexcel

I am using a "process class" witch performs some loads of Excel files, some getCell and setCell. Furthermore some writes to output.xlsx. The process class will also echo the peak memory usage. None of the input files changes during the process. Now when I run the process multiple times (e.g. because of PHPUnit) the peak memory usage will increase and I don't see why.

```
try{


$config = new ConfigDev();
if(file_exists($config->getOutputTmp())) {

    unlink($config->getOutputTmp());
}
$process = new ProcessRunner($config);
$process->run();
unset($config);
unset($process);


$config = new ConfigDev();
if(file_exists($config->getOutputTmp())) {

    unlink($config->getOutputTmp());
}
$process = new ProcessRunner($config);
$process->run();
unset($config);
unset($process);

$config = new ConfigDev();
if(file_exists($config->getOutputTmp())) {

    unlink($config->getOutputTmp());
}
$process = new ProcessRunner($config);
$process->run();
unset($config);
unset($process);


exit;
```

CMD echo:

```
\pathtoreporting\bin>php "My first Test.php"
10:19:58 Peak memory usage: 214.25 MB
10:20:23 Peak memory usage: 389.5 MB
10:20:51 Peak memory usage: 530.75 MB
```

At the end this means I cannot write tons of unit tests for my run method and this makes my code less safe.

Has anyone an idea why this can happen or how how to extract the part that where the high memory increases?

cheers,
Peter

Comment: You don't show what your processRunner() class actually does; but as PHPExcel objects contain cyclic references that don't always clean up in memory automatically with PHP's built-in garbage collection, PHPExcel provides methods to actually help clean up those references

Comment: Hi Mark, acutally it's gonna be difficult to pass that code as processRunner calls several other classes.
However I believe the key is about "PHPExcel objects contain cyclic references that don't always clean up in memory automatically with PHP's built-in garbage collection"
Can you tell me where to find the PHPExcel clean up methods?

Comment: Section 4.3 of the developer documentation explains cleating a workbook from memory

Comment: ah I found this already:

         $inputFile->disconnectWorksheets();
         $inputFile = null;
         unset($inputFile);
Now it's much better already. Is there more I can do?

Comment: The best option is combining that with PHP >= 5.4 (though upgrading PHP isn't always an option) because the more recent versions of PHP implemented changes to garbage collection specifically for this cyclic-reference situation.

Comment: The PHPExcel disconnectWorksheets() call isn't perfect on its own, because there are also cyclic references in stylesheets and other objects that aren't cleared down by that call; but it does eliminate the biggest of the memory leaks which is the relationship between workbook/worksheets/cellcollection/cells